# Need help with correlated subquery

Tags: postgresql, update, subquery

I have two PostgreSQL tables that each contain a column called `date_of_incident`.

They each also have a column called `incident_id` and this is how the tables are related.

I want to update all rows of table 1 by setting `date_of_incident` equal to `date_of_incident` from the corresponding row of table 2 where `incident_id` from table 1 equals `incident_id` from table 2.

Can anyone can give a sample `UPDATE`? I'd appreciate it.

`incident_id` is unique in both tables and it is how the tables are related, though not by foreign key or constraint (sadly).  I have the extra condition of `status = closed`.  The only complication is that table 1 has a trigger function on update and I need to examine to see how the SQL will affect things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres allows to join tables in an UPDATE statement:

```
update table_1
   set date_of_incident = t2.date_of_incident
from table_2 t2
where table_1.incident_id = t2.incident_id;
```

This assumes that `incident_id` is unique in both tables.

Comment: I think mine is identical to yours:

UPDATE table_1 AS t1
SET date_of_incident = t2.date_of_incident
FROM table_2 AS t2
WHERE t2.incident_id = t1.incident_id
AND t1.status = 'closed';

Yes, incident_id is unique in both tables and it is how the tables are related, though not by foreign key or constraint (sadly).  I added the extra condition of status = closed.  So this is called an "UPDATE FROM" query?  I will give it a try.  The only complication is that table_1 has a trigger function on update and I need to examine to see how the SQL will affect things.

Comment: @two4two If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.